# How to retrieve a particular row from an array in google apps script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using google sheets quite a lot, but now I am trying to use google apps script to get and update dynamic data retrieved from formulas into a static table.

So, I have a sheet called 'dynamique', with formulas retrieving, filtering and sorting data from other spreadsheets.

I want to be able to work on this data, so I am trying to create a button which would copy all the values from the 'dynamique' sheet into another sheet called 'statique'. That is, I want a formula which would check if the values from the column C of the 'dynamique' sheet are in the column C of the 'statique' sheet. And if the values aren't there, I want the script to copy them. (columns A and B are empty)

I've managed to get my script to work for one column, but now, I want to copy the whole line.
For example, if the value in dynamique!C10 can't be found in statique!C:C, my script writes the value of dynamique!C10 in the first empty cell of the column statique!C:C. But I want it to write dynamique!C10:J10 into my destination sheet (say it's going to be maybe statique!C8:J8).

Here is my code, working for only one cell.

```js
function dynamicToStatic() {
  var dynSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dynamique");
  var staSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("statique");
  
  var dynLength = dynSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length;//.getLastRow();
  var staLength = staSheet.getRange("C1:C").getValues().filter(String).length;
  var staRange = staSheet.getRange(6,3,staLength-1);
  var staValues = staRange.getValues();
  
  
  var rangeToCheck = dynSheet.getRange(6,3,dynLength-1,8);
  var valuesToCheck = rangeToCheck.getValues();
  var numRows = rangeToCheck.getNumRows();
  var staNumRows = staRange.getNumRows();
  
  
  for (i = 0; i<= numRows; i++) {
    var row = valuesToCheck[i];
    var index = ArrayLib.indexOf(staValues , -1 , row);
    if (index == -1) {
    //if (staValues.indexOf(row) != -1) {
      staSheet.getRange(i+6,3,1,8).setValues(row);
    }
    
  }
  
  var timestamp = new Date();
  staSheet.getRange(4,3).setValue('List updated on the: '+timestamp);
  
}
```

Now I can't manage to retrieve the whole line of the array, so as to be able to copy it using range.setValues(). I always get error messages.

Any help would be more than appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```
function gettingFullRows() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const shsr=2;//data startrow
  const vA=sh.getRange(shsr,1,sh.getLastRow()-shsr+1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  let html='';
  vA.forEach((r,i)=>{
    html+=Utilities.formatString('<br />Row:%s is %s',i+shsr,r.join(','));
  });
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModelessDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html), "Row");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So i did some re-writing to your code and made some comments in there. I hope this will make some things clear.

Array's are 0 indexed. So if the value is NOT found in the .indexOf then it would return -1. Also (for speed) i first push all the result to a array and then set the array in one "action" this saves a lot of time. The calls to and from a sheet takes the most time.

For the conversion to a 1d array i used [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

See [this link for difference in const / var / let](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/)

The timestamp string i updated with the use of [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

If you have some questions, shoot! (also i did not test this ofcourse)

```
function dynamicToStatic() {
  const dynSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("dynamique");
  const staSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("statique");
  
  const dynValues = dynSheet.getRange(1,3,dynSheet.getLastRow(),8).getValues();
  //This is a 2d array
  const staRaw = staSheet.getRange(6, 3, staSheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
  //Convert to 1d array, for the indexoff later on, this way it is easier.
  const staValues = [].concat(...staRaw);
  //to store the output, as a 2d array, inside the if you see i push it in as array so you have the 2d array for the setValues.
  const output = [];
  
  for (let i = 0; i < dynValues.length; i++){
    //i = the index of the array (row) inside the array of rows, the 0 would be the values of column C.
    if (staValues.indexOf(dynValues[i][0]) >= 0){
      output.push([dynValues[i]]);
    }
  }
  
  //Start by the lastrow + 1, column C(3), ouput is a array of arrays(rows), then get the [0].lengt for the columns inside the row array.
  staSheet.getRange(staSheet.getLastRow()+1, 3, output.length, output[0].lenght).setValues(output);
  
  const timestamp = new Date();
  staSheet.getRange(4,3).setValue(`List updated on the: ${timestamp}`);
  
}
```

Comment: Thanks @RemcoE33 for the time you took understanding and answering my problem. I tried  your script right as it was, and I get an error message: The parameters (number,number,number,null) do not match the signature of the method "SpreadsheetApp.Sheet.getRange". (for line 21 of your code...).
Since your code uses things I'm not very familiar with, like const, let and push, I have some difficulty looking at what could the problem be by myself...

Comment: Hi, i see a typo. See the length after output[0]

Comment: It doesn't give any error message now, however, it is not outputting the whole row as desired. It outputs only the column C.

I also changed in line 15 ">= 0" to "== -1", because I actually wanted to write those lines whose content in col C wasn't in my static list.

Comment: Can you share a mock sheet. With this info i can't help. not by seeing what is going on.